# Container which checks for the uniqueness of the content

Tags: containers, unique-constraint

Is there any datatype /container in any language which checks for the uniqueness of the content rather than the value or index before inserting the item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's called a **set**. Most languages implement them in some form.

Comment: Indeed. The most typical implementation is a "hash set", which checks for uniqueness by computing the hash value of each object.

Comment: to answer 2nd part of your question, "hash set" also index the items on the hash value of objects.

Comment: Not only the hash because that's just a necessary, not a sufficient condition. You still have to check for equality where the hash is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, one that comes to mind is Cocoa's NSSet class. The C++ STL also has a set class.

Of course, you need some way to define a unique object beyond simple pointer or reference comparison. For instance, in Cocoa, two objects are considered the same for the purpose of NSSet if they respond to `isEqual:` with `YES` and have the same hash code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with that is that the value can be ANYTHING so that's very open ended and not always pratical.

Answer (score 0):

SQL with a UNIQUE field. sets in Python. Filenames on Filesystems. Depends on how you define "content".